# Java generics: Bound mismatch

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class with this definition:

```
public class AcoProblemSolver<C, E extends Environment, A extends AntColony<E, Ant<C, E>>> {
```

Where `AntColony` goes this way:

```
public abstract class AntColony<E extends Environment, A extends Ant<?, E>> {
```

And `Ant` goes like this:

```
public abstract class Ant<C, E extends Environment> {
```

I was hoping to extend `AntColony` in this fashion:

```
public class FlowShopProblemSolver extends
    AcoProblemSolver<Integer, FlowShopEnvironment, FlowShopAntColony> {
```

But Eclipse is showing an error on the `FlowShopAntColony` parameter class:

```
Bound mismatch: The type FlowShopAntColony is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <A extends AntColony<E,Ant<C,E>>> of the type AcoProblemSolver<C,E,A>
```

Which confuses me, since `FlowShopAntColony` is defined this way:

```
public class FlowShopAntColony extends
    AntColony<FlowShopEnvironment, AntForFlowShop> {
```

And `AntForFlowShop` goes like this:

```
public class AntForFlowShop extends Ant<Integer, FlowShopEnvironment> {
```

Why isn't `FlowShopAntColony` accepted as a valid parameter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
A extends AntColony<E, Ant<C, E>>
```

The third parameter of `AcoProblemSolver` has the restriction `extends AntColony<E, Ant<C, E>>`. The second parameter of `AntColony` must be **exactly** `Ant<C, E>` and you're trying to pass a subclass of `Ant`. Try:

```
A extends AntColony<E, ? extends Ant<C, E>>
```

You may want other similar `? extends` clauses elsewhere.